# Virtual directory in the project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

In `IIS` under the site I can create a virtual directory which has a different phisical path.
Can I somehow do the same in `ASP.NET MVC` project? Something like adding a directory which links to a different directory.

The problem is I have some folder outside the site which contains images. I added that folder in `IIS` under site as `Dropbox`, which points to completely different location:

[image]

Now I also use such paths in the app with `Server.MapPath`:

`"~/Dropbox/Dev/Product/Images"`

This all works when I publish in `IIS`. But how can I do the same locally debugging? Is there a way to add virtual directory to my project in `Visual Studio`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that your are running your website using IIS Express. You can find your website IIS Express configuration file by right clicking the IIS Express tray icon and then show all applications. Select your website and then click on the config path as shown in screenshot

[image]

In config file, find your website `site` element and then you can add new `virtualDirectory` element like this:

```
 <site name="Website1" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="website1">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Projects/Website1" />
                    <virtualDirectory path="/Images" physicalPath="C:/Images" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54558:localhost" />
               /bindings>
            </site>
```

Here you can see Images virtual directory is added.